# Should we avoid IEnumerable as an input when designing public API?

Tags: c#, api, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

Consider following example.

Assume I developed a library that will be used by a third party. The library has a method that accepts `IEnumerable`, which is nice because it abstracts from the implementation of the collection passed. However, lazy evaluation occurs when I retrieve the input parameter.

```
public interface IStorage<in T>
{
  void Store(IEnumerable<T> values);
}

public class FileStorage<T> : IStorage<T>
{
  public void Store(IEnumerable<T> values)
  {
    foreach (var value in values) { /*Evaluation of IEnumerable*/}
  }
}
```

Some client uses my library in the following way:

```
  IEnumerable<int> values;
  try
  {
    values = new[] { "1", "2", "three" }.Select(int.Parse);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    values = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
  }

  var storage = new FileStorage<int>();
  storage.Store(values);
```

That will cause an exception inside the `Store` method where evaluation happens. If I designed the `Store` method to take `List<T>` I'd be sure that it is safely enumerable collection of Ts. The question is should we avoid `IEnumerable` when designing API or whether should we allow and enumerate it in safe context when needed as it might raise exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

According to the **Framework Design Guidelines** book by Krzysztoc Cwalina and Brad Adams.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2008/01/03/frameworkdesignguidelines2ndedition.aspx

Its is recommended that you do...

an extraction from page 252 (8.3.1)

> **Collection Parameters**
>
> DO use the least-specialized type possible as a parameter type. Most
>   members taking collections as parameters use the IEnumerable
>   interface

```
 public void PrintNames(IEnumerable<string> names) {
      foreach(string name in names) {
          Console.WriteLine(name);
      } }
```

> AVOID using ICollection or ICollection as a parameter just to
>   access the Count property.
>
> Instead consider IEnumerable or IEnumerable and dynamically
>   checking whether the object implements ICollection or ICollection

By the way its a great book and a worthwhile read, currently really enjoying it. 
P.S. the guys who wrote this, helped write the .NET framework

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't see a problem with an exception being raised from inside your method.
This *is* an error, and the user of your API should know about it.

Comment: Ok but I might need to do some cleanup (e.g. close db connection) so I'd like to know what can throw the exception

Comment: @nan: A `using` block is the standard method of handling that situation. Properly used it will ensure any exception will cause your connection to be closed.

Comment: It not only about disposing its about the fact that I need to restore some state on exception and I need to know about them.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your client's code is buggy is not your problem. Tell them to stop writing buggy code if they want their programs to work. You cannot protect them from the fact that those queries are lazily evaluated and they clearly do not know this.

It is your client's responsibility to handle what happens when you enumerate the collection, and *if* they have passed you a lazily-evaluated collection, then it is *their* responsibility to ensure that this lazy evaluation cannot throw (if those are the parameters you have defined). Breaking this invariant is *their* problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is good practise to have the most abstract interface as parameter in your library.
You define the contracts to those items in that way.

If you only need to be able to enumerate a collection, IEnumerable is a very good choice.

If you want to be able to Add, Index, etc items, IList is the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, the problem here is not with your API taking an IEnumerable. The actual problem is with the .Select call. Delayed evaluation is a feature of LINQ, not a feature of the IEnumerable interface.

So yes, you should take an IEnumerable as a parameter. The loading and management of resources is entirely under the control of the client, not yours. Just because the client could potentially pass in some implementation of IEnumerable which might cause delayed reporting of exceptions is not a good enough reason to sacrifice the maintainability and flexibility of your API.